# Elaborating very large array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing

I open a TIFF LAB image and return a big numpy array (4928x3264x3 float64) using python with this function:

```
def readTIFFLAB(filename):
    """Read TIFF LAB and retur a float matrix
    read 16 bit (2 byte) each time without any multiprocessing
    about 260 sec"""

    import numpy as np
    ....
    ....
    # Data read
    # Matrix creation
    dim = (int(ImageLength), int(ImageWidth), int(SamplePerPixel))
    Image = np.empty(dim, np.float64)

    contatore = 0
    for address in range(0, len(StripOffsets)):
        offset = StripOffsets[address]
        f.seek(offset)
        for lung in range(0, (StripByteCounts[address]/SamplePerPixel/2)):
            v = np.array(f.read(2))
            v.dtype = np.uint16
            v1 = np.array(f.read(2))
            v1.dtype = np.int16
            v2 = np.array(f.read(2))
            v2.dtype = np.int16
            v = np.array([v/65535.0*100])
            v1 = np.array([v1/32768.0*128])
            v2 = np.array([v2/32768.0*128])
            v = np.append(v, [v1, v2])
            riga = contatore // ImageWidth
            colonna = contatore % ImageWidth
            # print(contatore, riga, colonna)
            Image[riga, colonna, :] = v
            contatore += 1
    return(Image)
```

but this routine need about 270 second to do all the work and return a numpy array.

I try to use multiprocessing but is not possible to share an array or to use queue to pass it and sharedmem is not usable in windows system (at home I use openSuse but at work I must use windows).

Someone could help me to reduce the elaboration time? I read about threadind, to write some part in C language but I don’t understand what the best (and easier) solution,...I’m a food technologist not a real programmer :-)

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if it will be any faster, but you could try using `tifffile` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tifffile).  It will certainly save you some coding and debugging time.

Comment: I search a lot but I didn't found any lib that is able to read TIFF LAB (float16 coded). Thank

Comment: @dan2cil If you share your input data we could give it a shot to improve your algorithm

Comment: @BPL the image that I work are 92MB how I could share with you?

Comment: @dan2cil There are few available methods, uploading that data to dropbox could be a good one. I mean, yeah, i could start testing few options with little tiffs but I'd prefer to give it a shot to the real-data, testing your version and then improve it. So I'll be able to say how much my version has improved yours.

Comment: @BPL Dropbox ask me your email to share a folder, is true?

Comment: @dan2cil I don't recall but It should be possible to make a public dropbox link somehow

Comment: @BPL this is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2q484ljilnh9vx1/AAB1CSAoWmrrA_t51goJx_RCa?dl=0 where there is la LAB TIFF image the .png image for reference and my first 2 function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, your method is really slow indeed, try [tifffile](https://github.com/blink1073/tifffile) library, you can find it [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#distribute). That library will open your file very fast, then you just need to make the proper conversion, here's the simple usage:

```
import numpy as np
import tifffile
from skimage import color
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def convert_to_tifflab(image):
    # divide the color channel
    L = image[:, :, 0]
    a = image[:, :, 1]
    b = image[:, :, 2]

    # correct interpretation of a/b channel
    a.dtype = np.int16
    b.dtype = np.int16

    # scale the result
    L = L / 65535.0 * 100
    a = a / 32768.0 * 128
    b = b / 32768.0 * 128

    # join the result
    lab = np.dstack([L, a, b])

    # view the image
    start = time.time()
    rgb = color.lab2rgb(lab)
    print "Lab2Rgb: {0}".format(time.time() - start)

    return rgb

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = '/home/cilladani1/FERRERO/Immagini Digi Eye/Test Lettura CIELAB/TestLetturaCIELAB (LAB).tif'

    start = time.time()
    I = tifffile.imread(filename)
    end = time.time()
    print "Image fetching: {0}".format(end - start)

    rgb = convert_to_tifflab(I)
    print "Image conversion: {0}".format(time.time() - end)

    plt.imshow(rgb)
    plt.show()
```

The benchmark gives this data:

- Image fetching: 0.0929999351501
- Lab2Rgb: 12.9520001411
- Image conversion: 13.5920000076

As you can see the bottleneck in this case is [lab2rgb](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/color/colorconv.py#L1031), which converts from xyz to rgb space. I'd recommend you to report an issue to the author of tifffile requesting the feature to read your fileformat, I'm sure he'll be able to speed up directly the C code.

Comment: tifffile is not able to read TIF LAB file where L channel is UINT16 to be scaled in the range 0-100 and a/b channel are int16 to be scaled in the range -127-128. Is possible to do thi operation in the array with numpy?

Comment: @dan2cil When you say is not able to read TIF LAB, what do you mean? I ask you cos after checking your code was really slow I just tried directly tiffflib and I assumed this [output](http://screencast.com/t/GabBDMbTB) was the one you had linked. Do you have any example of the right output?

Comment: some example of the correct results are at the end of my routine, as: aa[470, 380, :] would be [26.09, 1.62, 0.22]. But following your example I would be able to solve my problem transforming the data after reading. I write my solution as soon as possible

Comment: @dan2cil I've completed my answer so you can accept it if you think it meets your requirements. Also added some benchmark & suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

After doing what BPL suggest me I modify the result array as follow:

```
# divide the color channel
    L = I[:, :, 0]
    a = I[:, :, 1]
    b = I[:, :, 2]
# correct interpretation of a/b channel
    a.dtype = np.int16
    b.dtype = np.int16
# scale the result
    L =  L / 65535.0 * 100
    a = a / 32768.0 * 128
    b = b / 32768.0 * 128
# join the result
    lab = np.dstack([L, a, b])
# view the image
    from skimage import color
    rgb = color.lab2rgb(lab)
    plt.imshow(rgb)
```

So now is easier to read TIFF LAB image.
Thank BPL